# convert vector of expressions to multiplication of matrix with vector of variables

Tags: matrix, vector

Suppose I define a vector/list like this:
`v = {x + 3 y, z - x}`

It can be expressed as a matrix vector multiplication `m.vars`:

```
vars = {x, y, z};
m = {
  {1, 3, 0},
  {-1, 0, 1}
};
v == m.vars (* True *)
```

Is there a built-in function to get this matrix `m`? I guess I wish there was a function like `GetVarMatrix[v, {x, y, z}]` that returns `m`. The closest thing I can do is the following:

```
M = Table[Mij[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}];
Solve[M.{x, y, z} == {x + 3 y, z - x}, Flatten@M]
```

But it doesn't quite work as expected, since it displays the error message `Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.`, which makes sense, but I'd like it to find some particular matrix, preferrably a constant matrix. Is there a concise way to do it in Mathematica?

EDIT: It would also be nice if it was possible to specify that I expect a sparse matrix, which happens often in many applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays), and take the second part which gives the linear part:

```
CoefficientArrays[{x+3 y,z-x},{x,y,z}][[2]]
```

> SparseArray[Automatic, {2, 3}, 0, {
>    1, {{0, 2, 4}, {{1}, {2}, {1}, {3}}}, {1, 3, -1, 1}}]